# Deserialize string property with empty object "{}"

Tags: c#, json.net

I consume an external service that it responses empty object "{}" for a string property. Could I use some attribute to avoid the exception?

```
void should_deserialize()
{
    var json = "{ \"p1\": {} }";
    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T1>(json);
}

class T1
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does it respond with if there's actually a string there?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It could response a right one: { "p1": "a right string" }, but other times: { "p1": {} }

Comment: I would definitely complain to the makers of that API, if for no other reason or goal than to prevent them from creating such an API in the future. `{}` is an object, not an empty string and having the same property have different types is not a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a hidden backing field to circumvent this problem:

```
class T1
{
    [JsonProperty("p1")]
    private object _p1;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string P1
    {
        get { return _p1 as string; }
        set { _p1 = value; }
    }
}

var json = "{ \"p1\": {} }";
// res.P1 is null
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T1>(json);

var json2 = "{ \"p1\": \"hello\" }";
// res2.P1 is "hello"
var res2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T1>(json2);
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as this is what I would have edited it to.